# Remove button from inside Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a Fragment that contains some Widget(Button, TextView and something else) all declared inside it's xml layout file. Now if a condition is verified, I would remove one of that widget from Fragment layout (not just hide, but remove). It's possible to do it programmatically from onCreateView method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you get a reference to that Button inside onCreateView, you can set the visibility of that Button to GONE, which I believe is the effect you're trying to achieve :

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

after you inflate your layout in onCreateView

```
container.removeView(container.findViewById(R.id.your_widget));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:
Button myButton = view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
((LinearLayout)myButton.getParent()).removeView(myButton);

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this.

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getView();
    parent.removeView(parent.findViewById(R.id.view_to_remove));
}
```